# Powershell Regex for string randomly divided with carriage return

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I am looking for an IP string in a block of text that will often have the IP address divided by a carriage return.  For example...

```
 e c t i o n                  
                                                                    1 9 2 
. 1 6 8 . 1 . 2 5 0       S t a t i o n
```

I would like to match the entire IP address.  I've tried doing a positive lookahead/lookbehind like...

```
(?<=1 9 2)\S+?(?=2 5 .)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A carriage return is just another whitespace character (`\s`).

You could use non-capturing groups (`(?:pattern)`) of 1-3 digits each followed by whitespace to match the entire ip: `(?:(?:(?:\d\s+){1,3})\.\s+){3}(\d\s+){0,2}\d`

---

```
$string = @"
 e c t i o n                  
                                                                    1 9 2 
. 1 6 8 . 1 . 2 5 0       S t a t i o n
"@

$Match = $string |Select-String '(?:(?:(?:\d\s+){1,3})\.\s+){3}(\d\s+){0,2}\d' 
$IP = $Match.Matches.Value -replace '\s+'
```

Comment: This does pull out the IP and goes one step further than what I was looking for.  I was ultimately looking for the return value of `$Match.Matches.Value` and will take it a different replace tact from there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Description

`((?:(?:[0-9](?:\s[\n\r]|[\r\n]\s|\s)){1,3}(?:\.\s[\n\r]?|\.[\n\r]\s)){3}(?:[0-9](?:\s[\n\r]|[\r\n]\s|\s)){1,3})`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- match substrings that look like IP addresses
- allow IP addresses to be spanned across multiple lines

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/sG8qS5/3

**Sample text**

```
IP address 1    1 9 2 
. 1 6 8 . 1 . 2 5 0       S t a t i o n
 e c t i o n                  

IP address 2                1 9 2 . 1 6 
8 . 1 . 2 5 0       S t a t i o n

IP address 3                1 9 2 . 1 6 
8 . 1 . 2
 5 0       S t a t i o n
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [16-43] `1 9 2 
. 1 6 8 . 1 . 2 5 0 `

MATCH 2
1.  [123-150]   `1 9 2 . 1 6 
8 . 1 . 2 5 0 `

MATCH 3
1.  [199-227]   `1 9 2 . 1 6 
8 . 1 . 2
 5 0 `
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (3 times):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 1
                               and 3 times (matching the most amount
                               possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and "
                                   ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          [\n\r]                   any character of: '\n' (newline),
                                   '\r' (carriage return)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
         |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          [\r\n]                   any character of: '\r' (carriage
                                   return), '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and "
                                   ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
         |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and "
                                   ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ){1,3}                   end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [\n\r]?                  any character of: '\n' (newline),
                                 '\r' (carriage return) (optional
                                 (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [\n\r]                   any character of: '\n' (newline),
                                 '\r' (carriage return)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){3}                     end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 1 and
                             3 times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [\n\r]                   any character of: '\n' (newline),
                                 '\r' (carriage return)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [\r\n]                   any character of: '\r' (carriage
                                 return), '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){1,3}                   end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Awesome solution and breakdown.  I see it working in the regex101 demo you provided.  It looks like it is built under php code with the modifiers gmix.  Unfortunately those don't seem to be available (from what I can tell) in powershell.  Tons of useful information here though.

Comment: Sorry, the expression had some extra spaces at the end in the demo. With those spaces removed and dropping the `mix` options the demo works. In powershell the `g` global option is enabled by default.